For $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ a quadratic field, $p$ an odd prime, does $\vartheta_K/(p\vartheta_K) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]/(p\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])$?
For $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ a quadratic field and $p$ an odd prime, do we always have that $\vartheta_K/(p\vartheta_K) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]/(p\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])$?
I have this assignment and I'm really stuck in it as all I can think of is that there must be a mistake in the exercise.
The case where $d \equiv 2,3 \mod 4$ is obvious. However, I don't see how this is still the case when $d \equiv 1 \mod 4$ and $\vartheta_K= \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}]$.
Can someone just tell me whether there's a mistake in the exercise or this is really true?

Usually a ring of algebraic integers is denoted $\mathcal O_K$, i.e., $\mathcal O_K$

Let us consider the case $d=1+4k$, where $k$ is integer.
We have for an odd $p$ the relation $2\cdot s=1$ modulo $p$, where $s=(p+1)/2$ is an integer. Below, we consider $s$ also as an element of $\Bbb F_p$, and then $2s=1$ in $\Bbb F_p$.
Then $(1+\sqrt d)/2$ has trace $1$ and norm $(1-d)/4=-k$, so we can write isomorphisms of rings...
$$
\mathcal O_K/p
=
\frac{\Bbb Z[X]/(X^2-X-k)}{(p)}
\cong\frac{\Bbb Z[X]}{(X^2-X-k, p)}
\cong\frac{\Bbb Z[X]/(p)}{(X^2-X-k)}
\cong\frac{\Bbb F_p[X]}{(X^2-X-k)}
$$
and we can substitute $X$ as $Y+s$, (or just build the discriminant, which is $1+4k=d$...) then
$$X^2-X-k=Y^2+2sY+s^2-Y-s-k=Y^2+(s^2-s-k)\ .$$
Note now that $4(s^2-s-k)=(p+1)^2-2(p+1)-4k=-(1+4k)=-d$. Write $Y=2Z$, and we obtain an isomorphism of the last ring in the above chain with...
$$
\frac{\Bbb F_p[X]}{(X^2-X-k)}
\cong \frac{\Bbb F_p[Z]}{(Z^2-d)}
\cong \frac{\Bbb Z[Z]/(p)}{(Z^2-d)}
\cong \frac{\Bbb Z[Z]}{(Z^2-d,p)}
\cong \frac{\Bbb Z[Z]/(Z^2-d)}{(p)}
\cong \frac{\Bbb Z[\sqrt d]}{(p)}\ .
$$
